# onAttach not called when navigating back through fragment backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

before commiting `FragmentTransaction`s I call `addToBackStack("")` to implement back navigation properly.

In every fragment's `onAttach()` I call a function which updates my action bar. This works properly when moving forward, but not when moving back using the back button. I guess `onAttach()` is not being called.

Any solution for this? Alternatively which function is called each time so that I can update the UI in that function?

Comment: Will onResume help you?  Or have you tried setUserVisibleHint(boolean)?

Comment: @Rollno1 is onResume() called every time? and isUserVisisble defaults to true and I haven't set it to false anywhere :/

Comment: when boolean vakue in isUserVisbleHint() method is true means that fragment is visible to user if the value is false then fragment is not visible. You can put logic of calling of fuction based on value passed in parameter